# Grails WARN: No SCM provider installed Stash GIT Repository

Tags: git, grails, grails-plugin

I keep having this warning **WARN: No SCM provider installed** when publishing grails a plugin, I actually want to make sure I have committed before publishing, How do I install an SCM Provider ?

I have searched on-line including this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961477/grails-no-scm-provider-installed) but not helpful information,

How do I use my Stash GIT SCM provider *or any other GIT repository* in publishing for my grails plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ignorable.

The original plugin publishing process used a Subversion repo and by default would create a project for your plugin source in addition to storing the binary in a tag associated with the version number. This was at CodeHaus; they're shutting down soon but for now you can see the old Acegi plugin source and binaries [here](http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-acegi/).

You could skip that (with the `--no-scm` flag) and store the code wherever you wanted, and once GitHub became popular most plugins used it or other source repos, so the release plugin was changed to only publish the plugin binary and the pom file.

Some of the related release plugin code was removed but not all, and this message is one of the bits that should be removed. At a minimum it shouldn't be a warning message.

Comment: Thanks, what about  git submoduling , can that be another way of source code commit verification before publishing plugin because it makes sense checking commit hash before publishing, or is it something that can be done as a grails plugin itself?